# Can we use a function like class in css so we can use it any element without repeating the same styles for each element?

Tags: html, css, class

I know the code is total mess, but I need to know if there is any chance to do this in the correct way.Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div class="row1">1</div>
  <div class="row2">2</div>
  <div class="row3">3</div>
<style>
  @class{
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 40px; 
  }
  .row1{
    background: red;
    style: @class;
  }
  .row2{
    background: green;
    style: @class;
  }
  .row3{
    background: grey;
    style: @class;
  }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like mixins here? https://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: You can try using [SASS/SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar in pure CSS, no need to invoke a pre-processor.

While CSS doesn't have functions in quite the way you want to use them, in your particular case you can select any element that has a class name starting with 'row'.

```css
[class^='row'] {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
}

.row1 {
  background: red;
}

.row2 {
  background: green;
}

.row3 {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1">1</div>
<div class="row2">2</div>
<div class="row3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do this is apply 2 classes to an element:

```html
<div class="row row1">1</div>
<div class="row row2">2</div>
<div class="row row3">3</div>
```

and

```css
.row {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
}
.row1 { ... }
.row2 { ... }
.row3 { ... }
```